# Деструктурирующее присваивание и пуш в массив в одну строку

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как-то достать переменные из объекта(способом деструктуризации) и сразу запушить их в массив?
Примерно таким образом:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

const array = [...{ a, b, c } = obj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то достать переменные из объекта(способом деструктуризации) и сразу запушить их в массив?

Как вариант...

Вот только зачем так упираться?

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
let a, b, c

const array = [...({ a, b, c } = obj, new Array(a, b, c))]
console.log(array)
```

Или еще вот так можно...

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
let a, b, c

const array = [...({ a, b, c } = obj, Object.values(obj))]
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Просто было интересно как это можно реализовать.